# The method that works only in one place, progressdialog

Tags: java, android, google-maps, progressdialog, marker

I have a method that takes lat/lng from mysql and puts the markers on the map.

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {

      myMethod();

    }
});
```

Everything in this way works.

**But** when i try to put this method with `ProgressDialog` markers do not appear. After push the button i see only "loading..." and "Done".

This is a way that does not work:

I

```
pg = new ProgressDialog(this);
pg.setMessage("wait...");
```

II

```
 myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {


          pg.show();


            new BackgroundJob().execute();
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "loading...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
});
```

III

```
private class BackgroundJob extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        myMethod();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    pg.cancel();
    }
}
```

what is wrong here?

Comment: You can only add elements such as markers to the map on the main thread

Comment: So how can I add progressbar when loading markers from a database? it takes too long time